# Are sysfs binary attributes allowed to return more than one page of data?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, cat

I'm writing a linux device driver that, among other things, exposes a readonly binary attribute in sysfs, the interface for which is

```c
static ssize_t read_dump_fifo(struct file *filp, struct kobject *kobj, 
        struct bin_attribute *attr, char __user *buffer,
        loff_t f_pos, size_t size)
```

When I try to `cat` or `hexdump` the file, after the first 4096 bytes, my driver will be given a zero-sized read (It is passed 0 for `size`).  Why is this happening, and how should my driver respond if it's not logically at EOF?  (A response of 0 would indicate EOF, but any longer response seems like it would be inviting some sort of a buffer overflow.  Currently, I return `-EINVAL`.)

Are sysfs binary attributes allowed to return more than one page of information?

Comment: If it's relevant, I'm on kernel version 3.4.0 (unfortunately before the enhancements to binary attributes in 3.11).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I had set the maximum size when registering the attribute to 4096...  Oops.

Comment: Go ahead and accept your answer to resolve the question.